# Use "UiAutomator dump" command while Appium is running

Tags: android, appium, appium-android, android-uiautomator, uiautomatorviewer

I need to run Automated tests via Appium, while there is another application which is trying to take UiDump and calculate some statistics. However, once Appium session starts, the application encounters error, since it can no longer capture the UiDump. On executing command "uiautomator dump", following error is encountered

137|j7maxlte:/proc/24005 $ uiautomator dump
sh: resetreason: can't execute: Permission denied
Killed

I understand this is a known behavior, but is there any way or work around to execute command : "uiautomator dump" while Appium session is active?